# How do you convert an NSUInteger into an NSString?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsuinteger

How do you convert an `NSUInteger` into an `NSString`? I've tried but my `NSString` returned 0 all the time.

```
NSUInteger NamesCategoriesNSArrayCount = [self.NamesCategoriesNSArray count];  
NSLog(@"--- %d", NamesCategoriesNSArrayCount);  
[NamesCategoriesNSArrayCountString setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",    NamesCategoriesNSArrayCount]];  
NSLog(@"=== %d", NamesCategoriesNSArrayCountString);
```

Answer (score 37):

When compiling with support for `arm64`, this won't generate a warning:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)myNSUInteger];
```

Comment: or `%zd` for `NSUInteger`, without typecasting that is.

Comment: @PaulPeelen Did you mean to say `NSInteger`?

Comment: My bad.. I meant, of course, `%tu` (since its unsigned).

Answer (score 7):

I hope your `NamesCategoriesNSArrayCountString` is `NSString`;
if yes use the below line of code.

```
NamesCategoriesNSArrayCountString  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", NamesCategoriesNSArrayCount]];
```

istead of

```
[NamesCategoriesNSArrayCountString setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", NamesCategoriesNSArrayCount]];
```

Comment: As of Xcode 4.5, this will throw a "Data argument not used by format string" warning.  Does anyone know the correct format?

Comment: Disregard last. I had a typo that I didn't notice for the longest time, and the typo was what was causing the error.  `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", myNSUInteger]` is still the correct way to do this.

Comment: The answer by @andreas-ley is more accurate.  ``%d`` is the format string for a *signed* integer.  NSUInteger is an *unsigned long* integer.  Using ``%lu`` is needed once the overlap between the unsigned and signed range is exceeded, otherwise a negative value will be printed when in fact the number is positive.

Answer (score 6):

When compiling for `arm64`, use the following to avoid warnings:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%tu", myNSUInteger];
```

Or, in your case:

```
NSUInteger namesCategoriesNSArrayCount = [self.NamesCategoriesNSArray count];  
NSLog(@"--- %tu", namesCategoriesNSArrayCount);  
[namesCategoriesNSArrayCountString setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%tu", namesCategoriesNSArrayCount]];  
NSLog(@"=== %@", namesCategoriesNSArrayCountString);
```

*(Also, tip: Variables start with lowercase. Info: [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html))*

Comment: Note that while `tu` works right now, it isn't guaranteed to. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893880/alternatives-to-type-casting-when-formatting-nsuinteger-on-32-and-64-bit-archi

Comment: Very true. I didn't know that actually. Good to keep in mind for the future.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use:

```
NSString *rowString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",  @(row)];
```

where row is a NSUInteger.

Answer (score 0):

This [String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1)  article from Apple is specific when you need to format Apple types:

> OS X uses several data types—NSInteger, NSUInteger,CGFloat, and CFIndex—to provide a consistent means of representing values in 32- and 64-bit environments. In a 32-bit environment, NSInteger and NSUInteger are defined as int and unsigned int, respectively. In 64-bit environments, NSInteger and NSUInteger are defined as long and unsigned long, respectively. To avoid the need to use different printf-style type specifiers depending on the platform, you can use the specifiers shown in Table 3. Note that in some cases you may have to cast the value.

- `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)value]` : NSInteger displayed as decimal
- `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lx", (long)value]` : NSInteger displayed as hex
- `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)value]` : NSUInteger displayed as decimal
- `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lx", (unsigned long)value]` : NSUInteger displayed as hex
- `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", value]` : CGFloat
- `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)value]` : CFIndex displayed as decimal
- `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lx", (long)value]` : CFIndex displayed as hex

See the article for more details.