# NSHTTPURLResponse's initWithURL method crashes if we set header "Content-Length"

Tags: objective-c, ios, header, crash, nshttpurlresponse

Here's some code, where we set up an `NSHTTPURLResponse` object:

```
NSString * data = @"response successful";
NSUInteger length = [data length];
NSDictionary * headersDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:length], @"Content-Length", nil];

NSHTTPURLResponse * response = [[NSHTTPURLResponse alloc] initWithURL:[request URL] statusCode:200 HTTPVersion:@"1.1" headerFields:headersDict];
```

The following code will crash at the last line if we put `headersDict` as parameter.

> error: testReportAppOpenToAdMobWithAppstoreId (AdTrackerTests) failed: -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xf653f40

I don't know why it crashes. Debugging shows that `headersDict` is good, I suspect a bug on Apple's part.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSHTTPURLResponse` is probably expecting an `NSString`, not an `NSNumber`. Try converting the `length` value to an `NSString`.

Comment: every key and value in `NSHTTPURLResponse` header is expecting an `NSString`... Oh My 2 hours....

Comment: Hello, how to fix it?

Comment: @Jerome Use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long) length]` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/20434633/211292