# Alternatives to type casting when formatting NS(U)Integer on 32 and 64 bit architectures?

Tags: ios, objective-c, printf, nsinteger

With the 64 bit version of iOS we can't use `%d` and `%u` anymore to format `NSInteger` and `NSUInteger`. Because for 64 bit those are typedef'd to `long` and `unsigned long` instead of `int` and `unsigned int`.

So Xcode will throw warnings if you try to format NSInteger with %d. Xcode is nice to us and offers an replacement for those two cases, which consists of a l-prefixed format specifier and a typecast to long. Then our code basically looks like this:

```
NSLog(@"%ld", (long)i);
NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)u);
```

Which, if you ask me, is a pain in the eye.

A couple of days ago someone at Twitter mentioned the format specifiers `%zd` to format signed variables and `%tu` to format unsigned variables on 32 and 64 bit plattforms.

```
NSLog(@"%zd", i);
NSLog(@"%tu", u);
```

Which seems to work. And which I like more than typecasting.

But I honestly have no idea why those work. Right now both are basically magic values for me.

I did a bit of research and figured out that the `z` prefix means that the following format specifier has the same size as `size_t`. But I have absolutely no idea what the prefix `t` means. So I have two questions:

What exactly do `%zd` and `%tu` mean?

And is it safe to use `%zd` and `%tu` instead of Apples suggestion to typecast to long?

---

*I am aware of similar questions and Apples 64-Bit Transition guides, which all recommend the `%lu (unsigned long)` approach. I am asking for an alternative to type casting.*

Comment: What about @"%i". I think it will work ,)

Comment: @AugustinePA: `%i` is exactly equivalent to `%d` and does not help here. Unfortunately, there is no format specifier for NS(U)Integer.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

From http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html:

- **z**
  Specifies that a following [...] conversion specifier applies to a `size_t` or the corresponding signed integer type argument;
- **t**
  Specifies that a following [...] conversion specifier applies to a `ptrdiff_t` or the corresponding unsigned type argument;

And from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Size_t#Size_and_pointer_difference_types:

- `size_t` is used to represent the size of any object (including arrays) in the particular implementation. It is used as the return type of the `sizeof` operator.
- `ptrdiff_t` is used to represent the difference between pointers.

On the current OS X and iOS platforms we have

```
typedef __SIZE_TYPE__ size_t;
typedef __PTRDIFF_TYPE__ ptrdiff_t;
```

where `__SIZE_TYPE__` and `__PTRDIFF_TYPE__` are predefined by the
compiler. For 32-bit the compiler defines

```
#define __SIZE_TYPE__ long unsigned int
#define __PTRDIFF_TYPE__ int
```

and for 64-bit the compiler defines

```
#define __SIZE_TYPE__ long unsigned int
#define __PTRDIFF_TYPE__ long int
```

(This may have changed between Xcode versions. Motivated by @user102008's 
comment, I have checked this with Xcode 6.2 and updated the answer.)

So `ptrdiff_t` and `NSInteger` are both typedef'd to the *same type*:
`int` on 32-bit and `long` on 64-bit. Therefore

```
NSLog(@"%td", i);
NSLog(@"%tu", u);
```

work correctly and compile without warnings on all current
iOS and OS X platforms.

`size_t` and `NSUInteger` have the same size on all platforms, but
they are not the same type, so

```
NSLog(@"%zu", u);
```

actually gives a warning when compiling for 32-bit.

But this relation is not fixed in any standard (as far as I know), therefore I would
***not*** consider it safe (in the same sense as assuming that `long` has the same size
as a pointer is not considered safe). It might break in the future.

The only alternative to type casting that I know of is from the answer to "[Foundation types when compiling for arm64 and 32-bit architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18848716/foundation-types-when-compiling-for-arm64-and-32-bit-architecture)", using preprocessor macros:

```
// In your prefix header or something
#if __LP64__
#define NSI "ld"
#define NSU "lu"
#else
#define NSI "d"
#define NSU "u"
#endif

NSLog(@"i=%"NSI, i);
NSLog(@"u=%"NSU, u);
```

Comment: Thank you. The "accidentally the same size" part is basically what I thought when I first heard about `zd` and `tu`. I guess I stick with type casting then, the #define stuff looks even worse.

Comment: Additional documentation from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1

Comment: "Now size_t and ptrdiff_t accidentally have the same size as NS(U)Integer on Apple's current 32-bit and 64-bit architectures." The same thing is true for `long`/`unsigned long`, but why is there a warning when using `%ld`/`%lu` without a cast? Also, `%zu` generates a warning even as you say it should work similarly to `%tu`.

Comment: @user102008: You are right, my argumentation was wrong. The real reason is not that they have the same size, but that `ptrdiff_t` and `NSInteger` are both typedef'd to the same type (int or long). I have updated the answer accordingly. And yes, `NSLog(@"%zu", u);` generates a warning on 32-bit. Perhaps I did not check it correctly, or that changed since then. And I wonder why `NSLog(@"%zd", i);` does *not* generate a warning on 32-bit.

Answer (score 11):

I prefer to just use an `NSNumber` instead:

```
NSInteger myInteger = 3;
NSLog(@"%@", @(myInteger));
```

This does not work in all situations, but I've replaced most of my NS(U)Integer formatting with the above.

Comment: I like this and in some cases wouldn't hesitate to use it. Just keep in mind that there is some overhead to creating & destroying the temporary object and its description. Oh, and you lose field width & precision specifiers (for a CGFloat for example).

Answer (score 2):

According to [Building 32-bit Like 64-bit](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Cocoa64BitGuide/64BitChangesCocoa/64BitChangesCocoa.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004247-CH4-SW2), another solution is to define the `NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64` macro, and then you can simply use the `%ld` and `%lu` specifiers with `NSInteger` and `NSUInteger` without casting and without warnings.