# UITableView show row number from 0

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

I get this error, when compiling project for real phone.

> format specifies type 'long' but the argument has type 'int'

On simulator all work fine.

If replace "%d" with "%ld" I get this:

> format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'long'

In this code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"page %d", indexPath.row+1]; // <-
    }
    return cell;
}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

indexPath.row is an NSInteger. This will be 32-bits on a 32-bit compile or 64-bits on 64-bit compile. When I got this error in Xcode the message said to use %ld in the format string and cast the value to a long.

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"page %ld", (long)(indexPath.row+1]);
```

This fixed the problem for both 32-bit and 64-bit builds. Don't cast to int because on a 64-bit build this will narrow the 64-bit value to 32-bits.

If using NSUInteger use %lu as the format and cast to unsigned long.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893880/alternatives-to-type-casting-when-formatting-nsuinteger-on-32-and-64-bit-archi) has some other alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

replace this line with this

```
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"page %d",(int) indexPath.row+1]; // <-
```